# No objects fetched from Parse Array column when Edited in Data Browser

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, date, parse-platform

I'm storing date into an Array column in parse.com to control the expiration date of my app's subscription.

1 - Store this date from app to parse's Server. Ex: `[{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-10-23T02:23:55.730Z"}]`

2 - I can read it back from the server. Ok.

3 - Edit this value from Data Browser. Ex: `[{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-10-23T02:23:55.730Z"}]`

4 - I can no longer read it. I get `nil` when fetching it on the app.

Parse does not support changing arrays from Data Browser ? What could be happening ?

**UPDATE:** Code i'm using to Fetch AND to Set the date:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetch];
//
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
// IF the date has been changed from Data Browser, serverDate above will return 0 objects.
NSDate *serverDate = [user[kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey] lastObject];
NSDate *localDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
//
if ([serverDate compare:localDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serverDate forKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
//
NSDate *expirationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
NSArray *arrayTemp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:expirationDate, nil];
//
[user setObject:arrayTemp forKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
[user saveInBackground];
```

I wanna be able to change this value in the Data Browser so that i can give users extra days on subscription, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Your quest is unclear - could you please add a source code example and list where and how you are fetching the data after editing in the data browser?  Also, why are you editing data in the Data Browser directly?

Comment: @RyanKreager Updated with code sample.
I wanna be able to change this value in the Data Browser so that i can give users extra days on subscription, for a variety of reasons.